# Can I import data from roboform 7 to lastpass without downgrade roboform to an earlier version?

Tags: export, import, lastpass, roboform

According to [LastPass's support](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=806) :

> Roboform has changed their export function in version 7. For this
>   reason, Roboform users who are interested in trying LastPass must
>   downgrade to an earlier version of 6 in order to fully import your
>   data to LastPass.

I do not want to downgrade roboform to an earlier version. Is there an easier way ?